# ASP.NET Development from Different cities at the Same time

Tags: asp.net

Sir I am a student, I want to develop ASP.NET website. There are 2 developers in the team. So, how can I develop the website at the same time from 2 different locations (1 developer is residing in one city and another one is in another city). Please guide me about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a source control system that will allow for distributed teams.  Git/Github is one of the first ones that come to mind.  There is a bit of a learning curve, but it should fit nicely for your needs.

https://github.com/

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft offers free TFS hosting. It integrates with Visual Studio nicely and is much more intuitive for a new comer for simple uses than Git/Github. You can find info on the free plan here: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you need source control.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) is a common choice for this, and it's very powerful, but it can be pretty heavy for a beginner. Mercurial is similar, and something like [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) makes it somewhat easier to use (there is a TortoiseGit as well, but the complexity of Git can have you back at the command line fairly frequently). Microsoft's solution is [TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ff637362.aspx), which integrates with Visual Studio and includes a load of very nice tools.

As for hosting, there's [GitHub](https://github.com), but like Git, that can be a bit tricky to get into. For Mercurial (and Git as well), there's [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which is easier to use. For TFS (and now supporting Git as well), Microsoft offers the [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/), which is free for small teams.

It depends what you're after. Personally, for a small team of relatively inexperienced developers I'd recommend Bitbucket with TortoiseHg. If you're feeling adventurous, then use Git instead (but still with Bitbucket because I much prefer their UI) because Git is well worth learning. If you really want a high level of IDE integration then TFS is the way to go, although you can replicate parts of that funcitonality with various VS plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) with [GitHub](https://github.com/) or Git with [Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/) for `Source Control Management`

[Trello](https://trello.com/) or Scrum that comes with Team Foundation for `User Story`